# Kafka on RHEL gives me "Classpath Is Empty"

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, rhel7

I'm trying to install Kafka 2.6.0 on a Red Hat VM.  When I try to start Zookeeper, I get:

"Classpath is empty. Please build the project first..."

I have the following Java Version, which is Java 8 as far as I understand:

openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)

Is there something I need to do to set a "Classpath" environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

I updated `.bashrc` for my users and the Classpath error went away.

Source: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-centos-fedora-rhel